# What package is the actuator base path stored?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am looking to log all of my Spring-Boot project's request.  My pointcuts work fine for my programming, and I can get the sub paths, but not the base actuator path.

- com.example.demo..*.*(..) - This works for my programming
- org.springframework.boot.actuate..*.*(..) - This works for paths like http://localhost:8080/actuator/info or http://localhost:8080/actuator/health.  This works

None of my pointcuts work for just "http://localhost:8080/actuator" with no other path.  I have tried looking through the org.springframework.boot.actuate paths and through the actuator jar to see if I missed a path, but I cannot find anything.  I've looked through org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure, but that doesn't seem to be right.

I just need to capture it and log the request, but I cannot find http://localhost:8080/actuator

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save someone else the trouble.

The class that serves http://yourhost:8080/actuator base path is

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/0a4c26532dff6f3fa1bf6d2e1c2a74549191117a/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/web/servlet/WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java

The programming that handles the page, is around line 76 (in current version).  Unfortunately, it is an inner class that is not public and Spring AOP doesn't seem to be able to find it.

So, if you are able to, probably the Filter answer above is good, but doing Spring AOP cannot go against that class directly.  Unfortunately, the Filter may not work in my situation, but someone else might be glad for this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can log all request with defining `Filter` class. It works also `/actuator` request.

```java
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.IOException;

// Run as first filter
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Component
public class LogFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        System.out.println(httpRequest.getMethod() + " - " + httpRequest.getRequestURI());
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        // do anything after response
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey,  I am doing a few different types of logs, including a duration logs and so on.  I appreciate your answer, but I kind of need the path or class that serves the http://localhost:8080/actuator path.

Comment: @someone you can filter requests by using `httpRequest.getRequestURI()` and add duration logs. I don't know what else you need, I recommend `Filter` and aspect-oriented concept for your question.

Comment: Thank you.  The aspect oriented part is what I'm figuring out.  It looks like I might need to be in micrometer or flyway or hypermedia.

Comment: This is the class that handles the /actuator root path: 

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/0a4c26532dff6f3fa1bf6d2e1c2a74549191117a/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/web/servlet/WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java  

Unfortunately, @ismail durmaz, the ResponseBody is not in a public subclass and doesn't seem to be available to Spring AOP.  

I appreciate the help, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use Actuator `HttpTraceFilter` to log detail. You can log detail in a file or directly to database.

Sample Inmemory repository

```java
@Repository
public class CustomTraceRepository extends InMemoryTraceRepository {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomTraceRepository.class);

    public CustomTraceRepository() {
        super.setCapacity(200);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Map<String, Object> map) {
        super.add(map);

        log.info("traced object: {}", map);
    }
}
```